# Hammerjs not working on Chrome or Safari in IOS (made with Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, gesture, hammer.js

I'm working on an app that has a navdrawer and i added the gesture swipe with hammerjs to close the navdrawer when swiping left, the code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <button @click="toggleNavbar">toggle drawer</button>
    <div class="navdrawer" :class="{'navdrawer--active': active}">
      <ul class="navdrawer__links">
        <router-link
          v-for="(link, linkId) in links"
          :key="linkId"
          :class="link.classes"
          tag="li"
          :to="{path: '/link'}"
        >{{link.name}}</router-link>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
<script>
import Hammerjs from 'hammerjs';

export default {
  mounted() {
    const app = new Hammerjs(document.documentElement);
    app.domEvents = true
    app.on('swipeleft', (ev) => {
      const NAVBAR = document.querySelector('.navbar');
      if (ev.srcEvent.path.includes(NAVBAR) && this.active) {
        this.closeNavbar();
      }
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      links: [
        {
          name: 'LINK1',
          classes: {
            link: true,
          },
        },
        ...
      ],
      active: false;
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleNavbar() {
      this.active = !this.active;
    }
    closeNavbar() {
      this.active = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Some details about the code and behavior**

The #navbar element contains a drawer inside of it that has a style to put it out of screen when `active` is false and inside the screen when it's truthy, i created the Hammerjs instance on the `document.documentElement` so i can use event bubbling. When i scroll the document i check if the `ev.srcEvent.path` contains the #navbar DOM element i stored in a constant, and if it does (if the user swipes right on the opened navDrawer) it has to fire the `closeNavbar()` function. 
It works perfectly on desktop and Android, but it doesn't work on any Iphone i test it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was IOS doesn't recognize document.documentElement, changing it to document.body does the trick.

```
  mounted() {
    const app = new Hammerjs(document.body);
    app.domEvents = true
    app.on('swipeleft', (ev) => {
      const NAVBAR = document.querySelector('.navbar');
      if (ev.srcEvent.path.includes(NAVBAR) && this.active) {
        this.closeNavbar();
      }
    });
  },
```